# Azure Search Scandinavian normalization

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I need a way for azure search to return a Scandinavian characters `æÆäÄöÖøØ` for a normalized query.

Example: I have indexed contents such as "Älmhult" and I need for azuresearch to return the result for my normalized query of "Almhult".

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to take a look at the custom analyzers that are supported by Azure Search and add one to the index field that you want to be able to search that way.  There isn't a supported Scandinavian language analyzer out of the box, but you should be able to add an ascii folding attribute to a custom analyzer to get the results you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers

Comment: I have tried ascii analyzer and was able to make it work. Thanks a lot!